# Unable to build a groovy jar in jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am unable to build a jar in jenkins slave/master. tried different approach, however unable to resolve this below issue. The same command is helping in locally and am able to create the jar.

```
export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:$PATH
mvn clean compile -f /home/iburahim/workspace/automation/ -pl testproject -am assembly:single
```

Errors:

```
    10:03:29 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    10:03:29 WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.4.3-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.4.3-01.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
    10:03:29 WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
    10:03:29 WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    10:03:29 WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    10:03:32 /home/iburahim/workspace/automation/base/src/main/groovy/com/comapny/base/config/Config.groovy: 34 Groovy:unable to resolve class Map
```

```
    10:04:01 [ERROR] /home/iburahim/workspace/automation/base/src/main/groovy/com/company/base/sdk/connector/ExternalFilterConnector.java:[89,136] 9344. ERROR in /home/iburahim/workspace/automation/base/src/main/groovy/com/company/base/sdk/connector/ExternalFilterConnector.java (at line 89)
    10:04:01 [ERROR]    AdroitRESTDriver driver = new AdroitRESTDriver(myConfig.getConnectorByType("AdroitServer1").getConfigParam("applianceAdmin"), myConfig.getConnectorByType("AdroitServer1").getConfigParam("applianceAdminPassword"));
    10:04:01 [ERROR]                                                                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    10:04:01 [ERROR] The method getConnectorByType(String) from the type MyConfig refers to the missing type String
```

Maven, groovy3+, java installed in the slave machine (OpenSuse42). Please do help on this.

Comment: Seems you are using old java for groovy3

Comment: I already tried the groovy 2 also, the same error getting. Please suggest me the java and groovy version.

Comment: Cannot find type "String" seems to suggest you have not supplied correct classpath.

Comment: Can you include your Maven POM so we can see how you have configured your build?

Comment: groovy-eclipse-batch-2.4.3-01 is quite old.  If you are trying to use Groovy 3, there are much newer batch compiler versions available. The compiler adapter as well has been updated recently.

Comment: This is my build part from pom.xml
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                </configuration>
Please suggest me a right version

Comment: Even i am new to groovy, I am not sure how to set a class path in pom.xml or some other place in linux machine (I am using opensuse as my slave).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer. Issue because of local cli and Jenkins using different java version from slave machine. When i was checking java version in Slave CLI

openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.12.0) (build 1.8.0_212-b4 suse-34.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)

When i was checking the slave machine java version through jenkins, its returning

19:09:28 + java -version
19:09:29 java version "9.0.4"
19:09:29 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
19:09:29 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

Then I found the mismatch and corrected in jenkins slave configuration,

Just added the java home path as /usr/lib64/jvm/jre and ran the job. jar successfully created. I hope this info helpful to someone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLiNS.jpg)

Comment: I'm making this answer as right since question is triggered from my side and perfectly working in my environment.